# How to add folder in zip, when this folder does not exist in file system?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

The task is to create zip archives containing a tree of folders with files. But one nuance, these folders are not on the disk, there are only files with other names, and the tree is contained in the database.

I tried to use the standard zipfile, but when I tried to call the write method I got an error that there is no such folder on the disk.
How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a folder in the archive that is not on the disk, one must use the writestr() method. For example:

```
zf.writestr('folder1/', '')
```

In order to write a file to the archive, while creating a number of folders that are not on the disk, one must use the write() method, where as the file name specify its name on the disk, and as an argument arcname specify the path to it in the archive. This will create all the previous folders specified in arcname. For example:

```
zf.write('test.txt', arcname='folder2/test1.txt')
```

After these two lines in the archive will be folder 'folder1' and 'folder2' and in folder 'folder2' will be file called 'test1.txt' contains the content of file 'test.txt' from file system.